# Attach an object to the pipeline without DI on ASP.NET 5 (or extending HttpContext)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

**tl;dr**
.- Is there a way to include a property (extend) on the HttpContext of a custom class, the same as there's a User property which is a ClaimsPrincipal? I want to access HttpContext.MyOwnProperty of a custom class along all the pipeline (without DI).

*Long explanation:*

I've created my own identity system on ASP.NET 5 to get rid of the framework's umpteenth and ever-changing Identity System, of which I'm really tired of, and to get away of the use of claims, which could be very standardized but are also inefficient where you come to lot of them.

I use a typed object for representing a user access, and obtain it from an in memory (or from a shared caché) repository which is a service registered early on the pipeline, somehow as the current UserManager. Then I pass this object to the pipeline by means of mapping it's properties to a scoped service that I've registered previously:

```
services.AddSingleton<AccessManager>();
services.AddScoped<CurrentAccess>();
```

Everything is working fine but I'm wondering if there would be a more efficient way to attach the CurrentAccess object to the pipeline, other than having to inject and resolve it on every place, since it's broadly used in the application.

**The goal is to extend the HttpContext class to add a property of the CurrentAccess type, the same as there is a User property wich is a ClaimsPrincipal.** That would be great, but I don't know how to do it. Any idea out there?

(I've also tried another approach that is using the HttpContext.Items property, which is a Dictionary<object, object> where I can add my own object, but I don't know it's lifecycle and I would have to look for my item and cast it every time, what seems uglier than the previous option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to include a property (extend) on the HttpContext of a custom class, the same as there's a User property wich is a ClaimsPrincipal? I want to access HttpContext.MyOwnProperty of a custom class along all the pipeline (without DI).

You can't add properties to a class. That would be an awesome C# feature though :).

Comment: HttpContext is a public abstract class. Where are it's concrete implementations? Can they be extended as partial classes?

Comment: Are you going to cast to your implementation of that everywhere HttpContext exists today?

Comment: Well, yes... just for my projects. I need my custom object to be present in the pipeline just as the HttpContext.User property is. I've overriden all the identity system and the authorization, and would like to stripe it out, since I'm not very happy with the everchanging and ultra-interfaced nature. I've suffered too many versions of it along this years...

Comment: That sounds like a really bad idea but if you want to go that route then making a new HttpContext derived object and casting to it literally *everywhere* is a possibility.

Comment: Yes, casting it everywhere is a bad idea, better discard this. Maybe I can do it with the HttpContext.User property only, casting ClaimsPrincipal to my implementation. Do you know where in the code User becomes concrete (not abstract)?

Comment: Feels like there's a disconnect here. User is specified as ClaimsPrincipal in the abstraction. You're asking for something that C# cannot do unless you cast or sprinkle generics everywhere. You fundamentally *cannot* add a property to a type. 

The first answer on this post is the closest you can get.

Answer (score 2):

Keep registering your services the same way you are doing.

```
services.AddSingleton<AccessManager>();
services.AddScoped<CurrentAccess>();
```

Then create an `HttpContext.GetCurrentAccess` extension method that returns the `CurrentAccess` object:

```
public static class HttpContextExtensions
{
    public static CurrentAccess GetCurrentAccess(this HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        return httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<CurrentAccess>();
    }
}
```

This way, you can use the extension method as a convenience method in places where you don't want to a `CurrentAccess` dependency to be injected in the constructor.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var currentAccess = this.Context.GetCurrentAccess();
    ...
    return View();
}
```

Where makes sense to take a dependency take it, in other places use the convenience extension method.

Comment: That would not prevent resolving the service at least twice for almost every request (one for setting it's values and another one for using them), since the authorization depends on it. This is not very optimized, thats why I'm looking for an alternative approach. Ideally it would be an extension property, but this isn't implemented as of C# 6. Maybe subclassing HttpContext and adding the property? Is it possible?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about a performance issue due to `GetRequiredService` calls, unless you have done your measurements and tests and know that you have a performance issue with that. If you really want to avoid that, update the extension method to check if you already have it in the `Context.Items`, if not then resolve it and add it to the Items